# Java - NumberFormatException at linear search

Tags: java, csv, exception, search

I am having this issue with the `NumberFormatException` in my program. Basically, I am asked to read a `.csv` file separated by `;` and it looks like this:

// Column Explanation (not in .csv file)

id; Summary; Number; Employee1; Employee2; ....... Employee7;

```
"1";"Sony";"1600";"Markos";"Nikos";"Antonis";"Nikolas";"Vaggelis";"Markos";"Thanasis";
"2";"HP";"1000";"Marios";"Dimitra";"Nikolia";"Spiros";"Thomas";"Kostas";"Manolis";
"3";"Dell";"1100";"Antonis";"Aggelos";"Baggelis";"Nikos";"Kuriakos";"Panagiotis";"Rafail";
"4";"Acer";"2000";"Marina";"Aggelos";"Spiros";"Marinos";"Xristos";"Antreas";"Basilis";
```

What I have already done is create a String 2-d array or the `.csv` file called `temp_arr` and I am asked to write a method that will run a linear search by id and return that company. So here is the thing.

At first, I thought I should convert the input key from int -> String since my `temp_arr` is a String and compares the strings (which at that time they would be int but read as Strings) using `temp_arr[value][value2].equals(string_key)`. But I had a `NullPointerException`.

Then I thought I should better convert my Id's from the `temp_arr` from String -> Int and then compare with the integer key using `==` operand. This action returned me a `NumberFormatException`.

The process is this:

```
System.out.println("Enter id :");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
int item = input.nextInt();  // read the key which is an Integer
int id_int; // temp_arr is String and item is int, must convert ids from String -> int
for (int i = 0; i < temp_arr.length; i++)
{
   id_int = Integer.parseInt(temp_arr[i][0]); // Convert from String to int
    if (id_int == item) // If the Array's Id's are == item
    {
      System.out.println(item+" is present at location " + (i+1) );
      break;
    } 
     if (i == temp_arr.length) 
        System.out.println(item + " does not exist");
    }
```

**My error appears at line 7** and I do not know why.

Read File process:

```
String csvFile = "sam.csv"; // .csv file to be placed in the project file!
BufferedReader br = null; // ini
String line = "",cvsSplitBy = ";"; // columns asked to be split by ";"
String[] arr = null;
String[][] temp_arr = new String[1000][10];
int temp = 0;
try
{
     br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile)); //start reading the file
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) // while the line has words     
     { 
         arr = line.split(cvsSplitBy); // creating the array
         System.out.println(arr[0] + "\t" + arr[1] + "\t" + arr[2] + "\t" + arr[3] + "\t" + arr[4] + "\t" + arr[5] + "\t" + arr[6] + "\t" + arr[7] + "\t" + arr[8] + "\t" + arr[9] );
      for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
      {
           temp_arr[temp][i] = arr[i]; // temp_arr represents (is a copy of) the .csv file
      }
          temp++;
         }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally 
    {
      if (br != null)
       {
                try 
                {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 }
            }
   System.out.println("Done!\n");
```

Output (Image) : [image: Output]

Line 106 which is causing the issue is :
 `id_int = Integer.parseInt(temp_arr[i][0]); // Convert from String to int`

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html : "Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.". In short the String that is being parsed is not an int.

Comment: you are using temp_arr[i][0] . were you meant to say temp_arr[i]?

Comment: @DesirePRG No, the temp_arr is 2-D because I want rows and columns for the data

Comment: @copeg I added the Read File method

Comment: What about the text you are reading, and the Exception stack trace (for NumberFormatException should identify the culprit String)? Please post both

Comment: @copeg  So  should I  post the whole code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that your Integer.parseInt() is trying to parse a "2" WITH QUOTATION MARKS. That's the problem.

A quick solution would be to replace this line:

```
temp_arr[temp][i] = arr[i];
```

To this:

```
temp_arr[temp][i] = arr[i].replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Anyway, I'd like to suggest using a different data structure for your case, because I've done something like this before for a client. Have you ever heard of HashMaps? You can do something like a HashMap with an int key and String[] values to store your data in, and the key can be your id_int. Maybe you can try this implementation next time. It's a lot more elegant.

Hope I was able to help!

Cheers,
Justin

Comment: You saved me sir! At first it didn't work bu then I edited the .csv file and removed the "" from everything and then it worked!

THANKS A LOT

Comment: Only one more question. The program works when the given key exists at the array but it gives my an exception when the key is bigger than my id's and the part of the process that says that item does not exist is not executed. Now why would that happen?

Comment: Would you mind showing me the exception? I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: Add the image. I tried to initialise the temp_arr with the value "0" at the beggining but no matter what I do, the last 2 lines of my code do not execute (lines of the linear search)

Comment: Nevermind, I found it! The correct if should be " if (i > id_int) " and not "if (i == temp_arr.length) "

Answer (score 0):

Would help if you also posted some of your data file and how you are reading it in.

But, my guess from what is presented is if you add `System.out.println(temp_arr[i][0])` prior to the 7th line or run this code through a debugger you will see that `temp_arr[i][0]` is not an integer value as that is what the error is telling you.